# The notify-send bubble looks ugly with openbox. (yellow, black and non transparent)

Tags: 11.04, notify-osd, openbox

system: **ubuntu 11.04 server**

window manager: **openbox**

The bubble looks like this:

[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

is there any way by just editing a config file? (which i, by the way, didn't found, neither in ~/.config nor somewhere else .. )

Answer (score 3):

Install notify patched update from this [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~leolik/+archive/leolik), you need it to use the customization file. After that you need to create a file using `gedit ~/.notify-osd &` and paste the following code in to it:

```
slot-allocation = fixed
bubble-expire-timeout = 10sec
bubble-vertical-gap = 5px
bubble-horizontal-gap = 5px
bubble-corner-radius = 37,5%
bubble-icon-size = 30px
bubble-gauge-size = 6px
bubble-width = 240px
bubble-background-color = 131313
bubble-background-opacity = 90%
text-margin-size = 10px
text-title-size = 100%
text-title-weight = bold
text-title-color = ffffff
text-title-opacity = 100%
text-body-size = 90%
text-body-weight = normal
text-body-color = eaeaea
text-body-opacity = 100%
text-shadow-opacity = 100%
```

Save it and and test notify-send again. Here is the [source](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/05/finally-easy-way-to-customize-notify.html) for this information.

Also there is a GUI to configure notify-osd put toghether by the guys at webupd8.org you can check that information [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/tweak-notifyosd-notifications-in-ubuntu.html).

The other option is to recompile it with your own customization settings, if you need to change those you need to recompile.

Comment: thanks for the effort but it still looks the same.
maybe it has something to do with xcompmgr ?

Comment: No, you need to recompile it if you want to use customizations or you need to use the patched one [from this ppa](https://launchpad.net/~leolik/+archive/leolik) that supports the file you just created. So, add the ppa, upgrade it with the packages from the ppa and you can start using the customization file you just created ;-)

Answer (score 2):

`notify-send` and `notify-osd` are different packages and I think that caused some confusion here.  According to your tags you are referring to `notify-osd`, but in your subject you are referring to `notify-send`.  The answer above by Bruno allows you to change the style of `notify-osd` notifications through Ubuntu's Unity based server.

You may or may not get this working in Openbox, but you can easily test it by typing `notify-osd`.  If not, a daemon might need to be started up for it to work, or it could require Unity.

If that does not work and you are forced to use `notify-send`, to my knowledge there is no current way to style the popup box.